# Replace headers on export-csv from selectable list using powershell

Tags: csv, powershell

fairly new to powershell and I have given myself a bit of a challenge which I think should be possible, I'm just not sure about the best way around it.

We have a user who has a large number of columns in a csv (can vary from 20-50), rows can vary between 1 and 10,000. the data is say ClientName,Address1,Address2,Postcode etc.. (although these can vary wildly depending on the source of the data - external companies) This needs importing into a system using a pre-built routine which looks at the file and needs the database column headers as the csv headers. so say ClientDisplay,Ad_Line1,Ad_Line2,PCode etc..

I was thinking along the lines of either a generic powershell 'mapping' form which could read the headers from ExternalSource.csv and either a DatabaseHeaders.csv (or a direct sql query lookup) display them as columns in a form and then highlight one from each column and a 'link' button, once you have been through all the columns in ExternalSource.csv a 'generate csv' button which takes the mapped headers an appends the correct data columns from ExternalSource.csv

Am I barking up the wrong tree completely trying to use powershell? at the moment its a very time consuming process so just trying to make life easier for users.

Any advice appreciated..

Thanks,

Jon

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the `Select-Object` cmdlet with dynamic columns to shape the data into the form you need.

Something like:

```
Import-Csv -Path 'source.svc' | 
    Select-Object Id, Name, @{ Name='Ad_Line1'; Expression={ $_.Address1 } } |
    Export-Csv -Path 'target.csv'
```

In this example, the code `@{ Name='Ad_Line1'; Expression={ $_.Address1 } }` is a dynamic column, that creates a column with name `AD_Line1' and the value of`Address1`

It is possible to read the column mappings from a file, you will have to write some code to read the file, select the properties and create the format.

A very simple solution could be to read the `Select-Object` part from another script file, so you can differentiate that part for each import.

A (simple, naive, low performant) solution could look like this (untested code):

```
# read input file    
$input = Import-Csv -Path $inputFile

# read source, target name columns from mapping file
$mappings = Import-Csv -Path $mappingFile | Select Source, Target

# apply transformations
$transformed = $input
foreach($mapping in $mappings) {
    # collect the data, add an extra column for each mapping
    $transformed = $transformed | Select-Object *, @{ Name = $mapping.Target; Expression = { $_.$($mapping.Source) } }
}

#export transformed data
$transformed | Export-Csv -Path $outputFile
```

---

Alternatively; It is possible to convert the data into XML with `Import-Csv | Export-CliXml`, apply an Xslt template on the Xml to perform a transformation, and save the Xml objects into Csv again with `Import-CliXml | Export-Csv`.

See [this blog by Scott Hansleman](http://www.hanselman.com/blog/XSLTWithPowershell.aspx) on how you can use XSLT with PowerShell.

Comment: Thanks oɔɯǝɹ, I did look at that but the problem being the ExternalSource.csv columns really will be wildly different each time so the hit rate would be quite low, hence the need for something a bit more generic.Would the Xlst template be just as hard coded?

Comment: @user898205 you can create a solution with a file to describe the column layout, or with an xslt to do the mapping. In both cases the code would remain unchanged, as the configuration per mapping is in the config or xslt file. The solution with a column mapping may be easier to configure and use, but will be limited to only support column mappings. The xslt solution will be more complex to configure (xslt is a bit harder to use), but will ultimately provide greater flexibillity.